# Servicestack AspNetWindowsAuthProvider

Tags: servicestack

I am trying to get the AspNetWindowsAuthProvider working.  There does not seem to be an option to pass in a domain name, or to change the ContextType to Machine instead of domain and pass in a machine name.

When I use Postman to Post the username and password to the /auth/windowsauth service I continue getting back a 401 (Unauthorized).  I believe it might be because I don't have a domain and are using ContextType.Machine with a Machine Name passed in. I need to have both options available.  Is it possible to change this or am I using it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The [AspNetWindowsAuthProvider](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/Auth/AspNetWindowsAuthProvider.cs) looks at the Integrated Windows Auth making the HTTP Request (i.e. `HttpContext.Current.User`), it doesn't let you log in as a different Windows Auth User.

Comment: What about passing in a domain name or working in local machine context for testing.

Comment: Are you doing your testing in the browser or unit test framework like NUnit?

Answer (score 1):

To run IE as a different user, you can create a `.bat` file and add the following command:

```
runas /netonly /user:[User Name including domain name] "C:\full path\iexplore.exe"
```

You will be prompted a password for the alternate user.